# C#, multiple == operator overloads without ambiguous null check

Tags: c#, operator-overloading, null-check

**Introduction**:
I have a few classes which do the same work, but with different value types (e.g. Vectors of floats or integers).
Now I want to be able to check for equality, this equality should also work in between the types (such as vectorF == vectorI).
Also, it should be possible to do a null check (vectorF == null).

**Approach**:
My approach is to create multiple overloads for the == and != operators, one for each possible combination.

```
public sealed class VectorF
{
    [...]

    public static bool operator == (VectorF left, VectorI right)
    {
        // Implementation...
    }

    public static bool operator == (VectorF left, VectorF right)
    {
        // Implementation...
    }

    // Same for != operator
    [...]
}
```

**Problem**:
Using multiple overloads, I cannot just do a null check with the == operator, as the call would be ambiguous.

```
var v = new VectorF([...]);

if (v == null)    // This call is ambiguous
[...]
```

I'm aware of the possibility to use a ReferenceEquals or null casting instead, but that approachis a serious restriction for me.

```
var v = new VectorF([...]);

if(object.ReferenceEquals(v, null))    // Would work, is not user friendly.
[...]

if(v == (VectorF)null)    // Would also work, is neither user friendly.
[...]
```

**Question**:
Is there a way to implement the == operator in a way, that it allows the simple null check, and allows for equality check between the different vectors?

Alternatively, is there another way how I could/should implement this?

Comment: Seems likely that your Vector classes should really be immutable structs. Then the issue of `null` doesn't arise. (I'm assuming that your classes contain only 2 or 3 values.)

Comment: Sounds like [zugzwang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zugzwang): either good looking `==`  or `== null`. How about having methods to compare with vector of other type? E.g. `VectorF.IsSame(VectorI)` ? Compiler will show user mistake when he tries `vectorF == vectorI` and then user will search for methods to compare, tada, problem solved? Another thing: comparing `float` with `int` wouldn't be precise, how about casting `VectorF` to `VectorI` first and then comparing two `VectorI`?

Comment: why u need left-right overloads.. can u share us overload methods contents..

Comment: I think you can simplify a lot your problems adding an implicit conversion from VectorI to VectorF

Comment: @levent: I'm just used to calling the variables left and right, I've adopted this from other overloads, where the order could be important (e.g. with matrix multiplication).

Comment: @Sinatr: Your approach of using another method sounds good, although only if there's a relatively huge overhead to converting from VectorI to VectorF. As InBetween described in his answer, the value conversion happens anyways. I think your approach would be good if the Vector would be backed by an array for example.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I'd push back on the whole design to begin with. I would never implement `==` with value semantics between different types, I'd find it rather confusing: `instaceTypedA == instanceTypedB` yells reference equality (at least to me).

If you need this to work, then implement an implicit conversion between `VectorI` and `VectorF`. This is how the framework works. When you do the following:

```
int i = 1;
double d = 1;
var b = i == d;
```

An oveload `==(int, double)` isn't magically produced. What happens is that `i` is implicitly converted to `double` and `==(double, double)` is invoked.

Comment: Thank you. You are right, == should be reference equality. I didn't think of implicit conversion, as I wanted the call to be as optimized as possible. However, as the values would be converted anyways, it doesn't make much difference after all.

Answer (score 7):

You can turn around the comparison by using `is`:

```
if (v is VectorF)
```

This check will fail if `v` is `null`.

Comment: I don't quite like this solution. The semantics of what you are really doing are hidden in a "clever" trick; reading this code, its far from clear that you are checking for `null`, to be honest.

Comment: Well, it is quite common to type check using `is` (or `as`), although not everyone knows it does the null check too. Once you know that it is quite obvious that `null` is not of a specific type.

Comment: What is the improvement over object.ReferenceEquals except for the shorter code? I would assume that the is has quite a performance overhead for just a null check.

Comment: I guess there is not much difference, but you could test that.

Answer (score 3):

What I would do in this case it not to overload the `==` operator, and instead do something like:

```
public static bool operator == (VectorF left, object right) {
    if (object.ReferenceEquals(null, right)) {
        // handle null case
    }
    VectorF rightF = right as VectorF;
    if (!object.ReferenceEquals(null, rightF)) {
        // Compare VectorF
    }
    VectorI rightI = right as VectorI;
    if (!object.ReferenceEquals(null, rightI)) {
        // Compare VectorI
    }
    // and so on...
}
```

Comment: Ewww, sacrificing compile-time type safety to save repeating a null-check?